# Diagonal Matrix and Quadric Surfaces

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

In Pressley’s book he gives the following statement,’The proof depends on the following fact. If $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, there is a matrix $P$ with $P^tP=I$ and $det(P)=1$ such that $P^tAP$ is a diagonal matrix $A^{’}$. The diagonal entries of $A^{’}$ are the eigen values of $A$ and the rows of $P$ are the corresponding eigen vectors. What result is this from Linear Algebra? Another question is that for a given quadric surface how does one find the 3x3? Is it usually by ad-hoc method?

Answer (score 0):

There is a proof by induction here https://people.math.carleton.ca/~kcheung/math/notes/MATH1107/wk10/10_orthogonal_diagonalization_proof.html

If you have a quadric given by $$Ax^2+By^2+Cz^2+Dxy+Exz+Fyz+Gx+Hy+Jz+K=0,$$ then your $3\times 3$ is given by $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}A & D/2 & E/2\\ D/2 & B &  F/2\\ E/2 & F/2 & C\end{array}\right].$$